# Flutter 3d Model part by part integration

Tags: flutter, dart, 3d, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am working on a project in which i am facing some issues from few days and need help in this regards.
The scenario i have is that i have a gym equipment or machine e.g(chest machine) so the designer has provided me a 3d model .glb file and also simple images of every part of the machine, now i am confused what to do of it may i go with the images or may i go with 3d model as the thing i want to do in flutter is that first i have to divide the screen in two halfs and on right side display the 3d model and on the left side make some buttons which will be the parts of the machine or tags of the machine e.g(seat, cable, handles) and when the user click on the button so in the 3d model that part of the machine prompts to the front and highlighted and after that the highlighted part will also be clickable as when i click on it so it's color changed to green which will indicate that this part of the machine is ok and and when i double click on it it's color changed to red.
The thing i have done uptill now is that displayed the 3d model and tags both on the screen now just need this functionality to complete the work.
Thanks